# ModelForm with user-defined fields and choices from foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my app, I have `Study` as the central model. `Study`s have multiple `Strata`, and each `Strata` has multiple `Level`s. Users create `Allocation`s for a study by choosing one level for each `Strata` linked to that study, like:

```
class Study(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Stratum(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='strata')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Level(models.Model):
    stratum = models.ForeignKey(Stratum, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='levels')
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Allocation(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allocations')
    code = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
    levels = models.ManyToManyField(Level, related_name='allocations')
```

In order to create fields for the allocation creation form, I am currently finding all the `Strata` and associated levels in the form's constructor, but hiding the strata as the user doesn't interact with them:

```
class AllocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Allocation
        fields = ('code',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        study = kwargs.pop('study')
        super(AllocationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        strata = Stratum.objects.filter(study=study)

        for stratum in strata:
            self.fields[stratum.name] = forms.IntegerField(
                widget=forms.HiddenInput()
            )
            self.fields[stratum.name].initial = stratum.id
            self.fields[stratum.name].disabled = True

            self.fields[stratum.name + '_level'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=Level.objects.filter(stratum=stratum)
            )
```

Is this a safe and sensible way to attach the associated objects to the form? I worry that I will lose track of the connection between `Strata` and `Level`s when trying to create the allocation. Is this something that would be better performed in the view?